# Why 9th rabi-ul-awwal is celebrated as ed-e-zehra?

Tags: history, shiism, islamic-basis, islamic-events, eid

I want to know ,what is the significance of 9th Rabi-ul-awwal ?

Shia believes that on this day Mukhtar-al-Saqafi had send the heads of the killer's of imam Hussein to his family, after looking at them Imam Zainul Abedeen (a.s) smiled for the first time after tragedy of Karbala, hence they celebrate this day as ed-e-Zehra (Eid of the family of Zahra (a.s))

What is the authenticity of the above belief , I want to know authentic sources.

Comment: The answer depends on what you consider "authentic". To, me Quran and Sunnah is authentic sources of religion. What do you consider authentic?

Comment: celebrating something is never condemned in Islam , as long as you did not do things which are not allowed!

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, it is owning to the anniversary of “beginning of Imam Mahdi’s Imamate”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> i want to know ,what is the significance of 9th Rabi-ul-awwal ?

Eid is any day that there is happiness in that day. The significances of 9th Rabi-ul-awwal is that this day is the day that killers of Imam Hussain a.s. at Karbala were destroyed:

> One particular hadith which speaks of this day tells us that while in
>   a gathering with the Prophet of Islam, Imam Ali and his two sons,
>   Hasan, and Husain (blessings be upon all of them), the Prophet, with a
>   smile on his face, said, “It is on this day that Allah will destroy
>   your enemies and the enemies of your grandfather and it is on this day
>   when Allah will accept the actions of your Shia and those who love
>   you.  This is the day when the words of Allah came true where He said
>   (in the Qur`an): ‘So those are the houses fallen down because they
>   were unjust…’ ([27:52](http://tanzil.net/#27:52))  And this is the day when the Pharaoh (Firawn)
>   of the time of the AhlulBayt was destroyed…”

It is after going through close to 80 days of grief and sorrow in which we commemorated the murder of Abi Abdillah al-Husain (peace be upon him) and his family and friends in Karbala and the other Shahadats which we have marked over this period - including the loss of our 2nd Imam, 4th Imam 8th Imam, 11th Imam, and of course our beloved Prophet Muhammad (may the prayers of Allah be upon him and his family)

Also this day is the start of the Imamate and leadership of 12th and Living Imam, Imam Mahdi (may Allah hasten his return).

---

**Reference:**

[Celebrating Eid e Zehra (sa) & Beginning of Leadership of Imam Mehdi (ajtfs)](http://www.duas.org/eidzehra.htm)